# How to load subcategories for each category in angular 9

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, angular9

"
getCategories() {
return
this.http.get<category[]>
(environment.api+"/category") ;
}"

**Right now. I'm able to load only categories using above code. So can anyone say how to update the code so that i can load all my subcategories for each category through an another get request**

Comment: It seems you're calling an API. Check first the API returns everything you need.

Comment: Yes I'm using express API, and there are 2 separate get request for category and subcategories, And my question how to use these 2 get request together in Angular service.